# Show Categories posts in Grid

Tags: wordpress

Which file is called when category item from navigation menu is clicked.Please help me out.Post page is in grid view but once category item is clicked , it shows the whole content in full width.How to solve this?yup I am developing my own theme and also I am beginner.

Comment: Share example, code and/or link.

Comment: It is Solved.I create category.php and put this code.

<?php
/**
* Template Name : HD Paradise Category Page
*/
get_header(); ?>
<?php single_cat_title(); ?>
<div class="grid-container">
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="grid-item">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><span class = "post-title"><?php the_title();?></span>
    <span class = "post-thumbnail"><?php the_post_thumbnail();  ?></span>
    </a>
   </div>
   <?php
   endwhile;
   endif;
   ?>
  </div>

Comment: Great! Post it as an answer and accept it.